# Spring Cloud Dataflow: issue with updating stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to understand how Spring cloud dataflow server distinguish if an update to a stream has changes.

I have such a stream

```
{
  "name": "test-stream",
  "dslText": "source --username=test | sink",
}
```

Then I sent an update request and it went through. I can see the new property `test` added to the `source` on the dashboard

```
POST /streams/deployments/update/test-stream

{
  "releaseName": "test-stream",
  "packageIdentifier": {
    "packageName": "test-stream",
    "packageVersion": null
  },
  "updateProperties": {
    "app.source.username": "test"
    "app.source.test": "test"
  },
}
```

Then I sent another update request to remove the property `test`.

```
POST /streams/deployments/update/test-stream

{
  "releaseName": "test-stream",
  "packageIdentifier": {
    "packageName": "test-stream",
    "packageVersion": null
  },
  "updateProperties": {
    "app.source.username": "test"
  },
}
```

But this returns an error `Package to upgrade has no difference than existing deployed/deleted package. Not upgrading.`

Any idea?